# Make \infty symbol horizontal align with 8 EXACTLY

Tags: symbols, vertical-alignment

as image

[image]

```
\newlength{\abc}
\settoheight{\abc}{$\infty$}
\raisebox{.5\abc}{\infty}8
```

doesn't get desired thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can be used as `\Infty{123}` or `\Infty8`

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\MBoxA
\newsavebox\MBoxB
\def\Infty#1{%
  \sbox\MBoxA{$\infty$}\sbox\MBoxB{$#1$}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr(\ht\MBoxB-\ht\MBoxA)/2\relax}{$\infty$}#1}
\begin{document}

\Huge$\Rightarrow\infty8$

     $\Rightarrow\Infty8$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks. However, when the \infty symbol is replaced by \centerdot, the dot doesn't align with digit eight yet.

Comment: @dearmath: sure, it does!

Comment: @Herbert: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newsavebox\MBoxA
\newsavebox\MBoxB
\def\CDot#1{\sbox\MBoxA{$\centerdot$}\sbox\MBoxB{$#1$} \raisebox{\dimexpr(\ht\MBoxB-\ht\MBoxA)/2\relax}{$\centerdot$}#1}
\begin{document}
\Huge$\CDot8$
\end{document}` image could see [link](http://i.imgur.com/EeKuL.png)

Comment: @dearmath: the bounding box is wrong. Use package `MnSymbol` instead of `amssymb`, or redefine `\centerdot` with the definition of `MnSymbol`

Comment: `\raisebox` already provides the height of its content as `\height`, so the use of `\MBoxA` isn't needed.

Answer (score 5):

You can measure the height of a figure eight:

```
\newcommand{\hinfty}{%
  {\sbox0{$8$}\raisebox{\dimexpr(\ht0-\height)/2\relax}{$\infty$}}}
```

I get the same result, by trial and error, with

```
\newcommand{\hinfty}{\raisebox{.2484\height}{$\infty$}}
```

This assumes, as usual, that `\mathsurround` is zero; a safer definition would be

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hinfty}{\raisebox{.2484\height}{$\m@th\infty$}}
\makeatother
```